# Logstash doesn't write to logs

Tags: logstash

when I run

`sudo service logstash start`

it doesn't write anything to /var/log/logstash/logstash.log

Not really that good at unix, is there anything I am missing to make it write to the log?

I've installed logstash the yum way, as detailed in the logstash website

```
ls -l logstash
-rw-r--r-- 1 logstash logstash 80949 Aug 11 09:16 gc.log
-rw-r--r-- 1 root     root         0 Aug 11 09:15 logstash.err
-rw-r--r-- 1 root     root         0 Aug 11 06:17 logstash.log
-rw-r--r-- 1 root     root        60 Aug 11 09:15 logstash.stdout
```

Comment: How did you install Logstash? Can you share the response of ls -l /var/log/logstash to see who is the owner of the file

Comment: And also is there any other file on the folder such as logstash.err ?

Comment: @Nagginagaseyoshi edited the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Logstash can't write log info because the owner of the log file is root currently.
You should change owner of the log file with the command below

```
chown logstash:logstash logstash.log
```

I assume that the reason is  you started logstash as root user in contrast with logstash service is started as logstash

(See the contents of this file /etc/init.d/logstash)

Comment: it seems to be it, how do I start logstash as logstash user?

Comment: It has been defined in the config file in the value of LS_USER (see the my previous answer) and as default, the value is logstah, if you want to change user such as root, you can change this value. if the value is logstash you can just start logstash service and the service will be executed by logstash user.

Answer (score 0):

It seems logstash is writing log into gc.log. you can change the file instead.

Have you change the /etc/init.d/logstash file before?
in the file, you can find name field.
if the value of the name is logstash, the log file name will be logstash.log
if you want to change the log file name, modify /etc/init.d/logstash and change the value of the name to "logstash" (I assume that your current value is "gc")

```
name=logstash
pidfile="/var/run/$name.pid"

LS_USER=logstash
LS_GROUP=logstash
LS_HOME=/var/lib/logstash
LS_HEAP_SIZE="1g"
LS_LOG_DIR=/var/log/logstash
LS_LOG_FILE="${LS_LOG_DIR}/$name.log"
LS_CONF_DIR=/etc/logstash/conf.d
LS_OPEN_FILES=16384
```

Comment: So...better to wait another answer then.. :(

Comment: Did you check the contents of the gc.log?